# I have created a simple registration webpage and now I want to get a word file of particular format auto-filled with details. How to proceed?

Tags: python

I have created a simple registration webpage taking input values and now I want to get a word file of particular format (suppose a word file I already have with fields name, age, gender) auto-filled with details. How to proceed?
I am currently doing code on my mobile phone.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: what is a word file?

Comment: I mean ms word file. I already have a template and want to autofil it

Comment: take a look here i guess ... try some stuff and come back with some questions about actual code :) https://docxtpl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.